# Send form with document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I use an ajax based form. My Problem is, that I don't know how to change the java script  code to use a submit function. I think I must integrate in this code `document.getElementById("form1").submit();`  but i don't know how. I want to sent it over the submit function, because then I show if submit is post an answer.

```
   ;(function( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        if( $.fn.wizard ) {

            $( '.wzd-default' ).wizard({
                buttonContainerClass: 'mws-button-row'
            });

            if( $.fn.validate ) {
                $wzd_form = $( '.wzd-validate' ).validate({ onsubmit: false });

                $( '.wzd-validate' ).wizard({
                    buttonContainerClass: 'mws-button-row', 
                    onStepLeave: function(wizard, step) {
                        return $wzd_form.form();
                    }, 
                    onBeforeSubmit: function() {
                        return $wzd_form.form();
                    }
                });

                $wzd_v_form = $( '.wzd-vertical' ).validate({ onsubmit: false });

                $( '.wzd-vertical' ).wizard({
                    orientation: 'vertical', 
                    buttonContainerClass: 'mws-button-row', 
                    onStepLeave: function(wizard, step) {
                        return $wzd_v_form.form();
                    }, 
                    onBeforeSubmit: function() {
                        return $wzd_v_form.form();
                    }
                });

                $wzd_v1_form = $( '.wzd-ajax' ).validate({ onsubmit: false });

                $( '.wzd-ajax' ).wizard({
                    buttonContainerClass: 'mws-button-row', 
                    onStepLeave: function(wizard, step) {
                        return $wzd_v1_form.form();
                    }, 
                    onBeforeSubmit: function() {
                        return $wzd_v1_form.form();
                    }, 


                });
            }           
        }
    });

}) (jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: What library are you using that allows the `.wizard`?

Comment: what is this wizard() function? Do you have a concrete sample of code?
I guess you use this lib: https://code.google.com/p/ppe-pasquin/source/browse/trunk/PortalTrabajador/WebPortalTrabajador/Content/js/demo/demo.wizard.js?r=139 ?

Maybe you need to add a class to your form? And then by clicking the submit button, everything should work I guess...

Comment: Ok now i had posted the whole code above.

Comment: @Antonis - Yes it is the MWS Wizard Form. In the original Code it show me by submit the server response. But I want to make a submit. So I can say with php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) .... or something like these.

Comment: You should find the documentation of it if you want to use it properly. Maybe you should include a class in your form, I have no idea how it works.

You want to do a submit within javascript, or from the html?
I mean, the form does have a submit button, right?
And within javascript, a simple .submit() should be enough I guess...

Can you make a jsFiddle sample?

Comment: Yes the form have a submit button. But what I must change in the code above to make a submit?